# Is it possible to write a daemon to do cleanup on Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am working on a snapchat clone to get familiar with parse. I was wondering if there was a way to write a script that runs at predefined intervals and deletes messages that are over 24hrs old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a background job (https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs).
Next you schedule the task every 24 hours.

[image]